# RSpec FactoryGirl Class method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a self.lookup method in my Active Record.  What I want to do is use FactoryGirl to test the method.  When I call the class Repurchase.lookup(d, lp) it is pulling from the database seeded data instead of the test data.

in Repurchase active record:

```
def self.lookup(division, loan)

end
```

in my RSpec code:

```
rr = FactoryGirl.create(:repurchase, pricing_cat_id: nil, loan_id: 1)       
puts rr.inspect

d = FactoryGirl.build(:division, id: 1)
lp = FactoryGirl.build(:loan, id: 1, pricing_cat_id: nil)

rv = Repurchase.lookup(d, lp)  
#When I call this it goes against the database 
#HOW TO DO THIS (rv = Repurchase.lookup(d, lp) against test data)?

rv.pricing_cat_id.should eql(nil)

rr = FactoryGirl.create(:repurchase, pricing_cat_id: 1, loan_id: nil)       
puts rr.inspect

lp = FactoryGirl.build(:loan, id: nil, pricing_category_id: 1)
lp.pricing_cat_id.should eql(1)
rv = Repurchase.lookup(d, lp)  #HOW TO DO THIS lookup call??
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I see you mixing `build` and `create` in your code. `create` will create the new object and save it to the database; `build` creates it but doesn't save it right away.

So your variables `d` and `lp` are ActiveRecord objects living in memory, but not in the database. I'm assuming that your `Repurchase.lookup` method uses ActiveRecord calls to look for the right stuff in the database. So for those new objects to be visible to `lookup`, you should either be making them with `create`, or saving them to the database yourself by calling `save` on them.